# Is there a way to condense this code instead of using a big if-else block?

Tags: python, openpyxl

Writing a function that applies styles to a cell range, wondering if there's some sort of metaprogramming way to avoid having a big if-else block here. Like being able to get which attribute I want to set from a dictionary that maps from Type -> attribute.

```
def _apply_style_to_range(self, cell_range, style):
    for row in self.worksheet[cell_range]:
        for cell in row:
            if isinstance(style, openpyxl.styles.Alignment):
                self.worksheet[cell.coordinate].alignment = style
            elif isinstance(style, openpyxl.styles.Border):
                self.worksheet[cell.coordinate].border = style
            elif isinstance(style, openpyxl.styles.PatternFill):
                self.worksheet[cell.coordinate].fill = style
            elif isinstance(style, openpyxl.styles.Font):
                self.worksheet[cell.coordinate].font = style
            elif style in Numbers.all_number_formats: # these are custom strings I came up with so no defining type
                self.worksheet[cell.coordinate].number_format = style
            else:
                raise ValueError('unhandled style {} unable to be applied'.format(style))
```

Comment: Use a NamedStyle.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I was able to come up with

```
def _apply_style_to_range(self, cell_range, style):
    style_dict = {
        openpyxl.styles.Alignment: "alignment",
        openpyxl.styles.Border: "border",
        openpyxl.styles.PatternFill: "fill",
        openpyxl.styles.Font: "font",
    }

    attr_to_set = style_dict.get(type(style), None)
    if attr_to_set is None and style in Numbers.all_number_formats:
        attr_to_set = "number_format"

    if attr_to_set is None:
        raise ValueError('unhandled style {} unable to be applied'.format(style))

    for row in self.worksheet[cell_range]:
        for cell in row:
            self.worksheet[cell.coordinate].__setattr__(attr_to_set, style)
```

Comment: Use `setattr(obj, key, value)` instead of accessing `__setattr__` directly.

Comment: A few notes: 1) Use the `setattr` function, don't call `.__setattr__` directly, e.g. `setattr(self.worksheet[cell.coordinate], attr_to_set, style)`. 2) This won't work if subclasses are involved; if `style` might be an instance of a subclass of, say, `openpyxl.styles.Alignment`, it won't be recognized. 3) Define `style_dict` outside the function, or it will be recreated on every call (removing whatever savings the `dict` lookup provides over sequential `if` checks).